# JavaScript var inside string

Tags: javascript, string

I know that you can use `${}` inside a `string` to put a `var` but here it seems it doesn't want to recognise the `var` and it is not in the brackets

```
var str = s.toLowerCase();
        var counts = {};
        var ch, index, len, count;

        for (index = 0, len = str.length; index < len; ++index) {
            ch = str.charAt(index);
            count = counts[ch];
            counts[ch] = count ? count + 1 : 1;
        }
        for (ch in counts) {
            console.log('${ch}(${counts[ch]})');
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure something like this exists without defining an extra function to handle this?

Comment: It's typo , replace `'` with `\``

Answer (score 2):

ES2015 [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) require a back tick:

```
console.log(`${ch}(${counts[ch]})`);
```

Working example:

```js
const s = 'An example string with some duplicate characters.';

var str = s.toLowerCase();
var counts = {};
var ch, index, len, count;

for (index = 0, len = str.length; index < len; ++index) {
  ch = str.charAt(index);
  count = counts[ch];
  counts[ch] = count ? count + 1 : 1;
}
for (ch in counts) {
  console.log(`${ch}(${counts[ch]})`);
}
```

Comment: the problem is not in the brackets

Comment: What do you mean? Where is it, then?

Comment: i want to be inside 1 string

Comment: There's only one string literal. Could you please clarify what the result should look like?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the back tick. Use ` instead of '.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your string inside ``, not ''.

```
var myVar = 'hello world!';
console.log(`${myVar}`);
```